# I'm unable to use EnumProcesses in DevC++ v5.11

Tags: c++, winapi

```
BOOL EnumProcesses(
 [out] DWORD   *lpidProcess,
 [in]  DWORD   cb,
 [out] LPDWORD lpcbNeeded
 );
```

I keep getting "Undefined reference to EnumProcesses" on Dev c++ is there any Static link I can add to make it work ?

Comment: It should be part of the psapi.h library. Check the documentation:  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses)

Comment: You may have to link to `Psapi.lib`